# Не понимаю почему не работают внутренние роуты React-Router 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Никак не могу понять почему в приложении после деплоя на netlify не работают вложенные роуты если обновить страницу в браузере. И по прямой ссылке тоже 404. А если с главной страницы заходить через Link то страница открывается. Приложение собрано на CRA. В конфиг изменений не вносил.

Роутинг:

```
export const App = () => (
    <div className={styles.root}>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LayoutPage />}>
                <Route index element={<HomePage />} />
                <Route path="/create-new-entry" element={<CreateNewEntry />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

на страницу /create-new-entry я могу попасть только с главной по ссылке которая обёрнута в `<Link>`. А если прямой путь указать(https://gregarious-empanada-516283.netlify.app/create-new-entry) то 404.

Приложение по адресу: https://gregarious-empanada-516283.netlify.app

Answer (score 0):

Возможно ваша кнопка ведет на "/create-entry", а вы вводите "/create-new-entry"

Возможно вам поможет это
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271740/component-with-routes?noredirect=1#comment127695960_72271740